# What is the best way to give the same x and y data for each aes mapping for ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph baseball data in R and am having trouble finding the best way to do this.

I have a CSV file of the data, taken from [here](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=c,-1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318&season=2022&month=0&season1=2022&ind=0&team=0,ts&rost=&age=&filter=&players=0&startdate=&enddate=) and am trying to plot certain statistics on a scatter plot.

For example, something I was just graphing was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnA6P.jpg). Everything looks fine, but I want to make changing the statistics I am graphing easier.

Currently I have a bunch of geom_image functions for every team for every team, as seen below:

```
  geom_image(data=subset(team_stats, Team == "Blue Jays"  | Team == "TOR"), mapping = aes(x = HR.x, y = wRC., 
                                                                                  image = imageBlueJays), size = .1)+
  geom_image(data=subset(team_stats, Team == "Red Sox"  | Team == "BOS"), mapping = aes(x = HR.x, y = wRC., 
                                                                                  image = imageRedSox), size = .055)+
```

I have 28 more of these lines for the rest of the teams in the league. Initially I was thinking of doing a for loop, but I have no idea how I'd set the value for the "image" variable for each team.

So right now if I want to change a statistic, I have to do a search and replace for the stat I want to switch out. It'd be much simpler if I just had variables for the xstat and ystat and was able to just change those once, however I am not sure about how to do that.

If I set one of the variables inside aes() equal to something like `team_stats$HR.x`, gives me an error saying:

```
"Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."
```

I believe this is due to the fact that the length of team_stats$HR.x is just 30, which is the number rows (one row for each team). While the length of the dataframe is equal to 677, which is the number of columns.

What can I do here?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Wh not just put the `aes(x, y)` call in the original `ggplot()` call? Then the `geom_image()` calls can just have different data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.